# Wrong results appearing for date formula

Tags: excel, datetime, formula

I'm using the formula =NETWORKDAYS(start_date,end_date) to calculate the number of working days between an estimated delivery date and the actual delivery date of products.

It is working fine to some extent, however if there is a recorded delivery date but no estimated date, it provides a value of 29,600+. Similarly if there is an estimated date but no delivery date (ie the item hasn't yet been received) it returns a value of -29,600+.

What addition to this formula can I add to stop this happening?

Also, if the delivery date and estimated delivery date are the same, it returns a value of 1, when it should be 0?

Here's ideally what I want:

the two columns with dates in are E and M, and I want the following to happen:

1. When E is blank but N isn't, the value 'no est' will appear
2. When N is blank but E isn't, the value 'no del' will appear
3. When both E and N are blank, the value 'no data' will appear
4. When neither are blank, i want it to use the formula =NETWORKDAYS($E,$N) to calculate the amount of days between the two dates

This is the formula I have created, but excel won't accept it

=IF(E21=ISBLANK,(=IF(N21=ISBLANK,"no data","no est")),(=IF(N21=ISBLANK,"no del",(=NETWORKDAYS($E,$N)))))

Thanks

Comment: You should ensure that both start_date and end_date are given some valid dates. Otherwise, you will face this problem. Check : http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/excel-help/networkdays-HP005209190.aspx

Comment: What should happen if there are any blanks in either `start_date` or `end_date`? Excel counts days on the basis of 'start of the day' and 'end of the day', so comparing 8/8/13 with 8/8/13 will return 1 day (from morning of 8/8/13 to night of 8/8/13).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to your attempt:

> =IF(AND(ISBLANK(E2),ISBLANK(M2)),"no data",IF(ISBLANK(E2),"no est",IF(ISBLANK(M2),"no del",NETWORKDAYS(E2,M2))))

(probably could be abbreviated slightly, but relatively clear).

Comment: Thanks :) how would I add to that to ensure that if the dates in each column were the same, the value 0 would appear, rather than 1?